# Math equation are not centered when next to a wrapfigure

Tags: equations, wrapfigure, wrapfig

I'm using wrapfig, and while the text is properly aligned, equations behave as if the figure didn't exist...
I have found some examples of equations that are properly aligned, but it seems to me they are not doing anything fancy to get the proper result. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry} % 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\textbf{xxiii}\quad $\boxed{f(x)=\frac{\ln x-x^2+1}{x}}$

% Grafico
\begin{wrapfigure}[15]{R}{6cm}
\centering{
%% There is actually a pgfplot in here
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
}\par
\end{wrapfigure}

\emph{Dominio:} Considerando il denominatore e il logaritmo, otteniamo $x>0$.

\emph{Intersezioni con gli Assi:} se $x=0$ siamo fuori dal dominio. Se $y=0$ invece dobbiamo risolvere l'equazione
\[\ln x- x^2+1 \quad \to \quad \ln x= x^2-1\]
che deve essere affrontata graficamente: confrontando la curva logaritmica e la parabola. Da questo confronto deduciamo che ci sono due intersezioni con gli assi:
\[(\alpha, 0),\ (1, 0).\]

\emph{Segno:} Notiamo che il denominatore è positivo nel dominio considerato: il segno di $f$ è uguale al segno del numeratore. Per studiare quest'ultimo si rende nuovamente necessario affrontare graficamente la disequazione (il grafico è lo stesso di prima):
\[\ln x \geq x^2-1\quad \to \quad x\leq \alpha \vee x\geq 1 \]

\end{document}
```

The output is the following:
[image]

I would like the two equations next to the picture to appear centered with respect to the text, and not the whole page. Using equation instead of `\[...\]` didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full but miniaml exmaple that others can copy and test as is. Instead of external images one can use say `\rule{5cm}{5cm}`. Then we do not have to guess your setup.

Comment: If I add `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amamsth,wrapfig}\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` as well as an educated guess for `\qui` to your code, everything works out nicely. Whatever is happening is due to code you are withholding.

Comment: Provide a single document, not snitples and make sure it is minimal, aka remove irrelevant packages. This may seem annoying, but it is an important part of the debugging process.

Comment: It is the way `amsart` is configured, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124202/equations-in-amsart-crash-into-wrapfigs. amsart required the formulas to be centered in relation to the margins no matter what. And thus does not take things like `wrapfig` info account. (Personally I probably would not use `wrapfig` in the first place). In the link there is an answer with a manual fix.

Comment: `\centering` does not take an argument you should remove the `{` and `}\par`